# Why does nslookup resolve, dig resolve. but ping, wget, apt and curl do not?

Tags: debian

It's late at night and I am trying to get this setup working for my brother in law. End solution is going to run on a Raspberry Pi 4.

1. I start with a blank Debian 11 server in a VM.
2. I installed OpenMediaVault
3. I installed Calibre-Web
4. I installed Transmission-Daemon
5. I then shutdown the VM, added two volumes, and stared her up.

I want to partition the one volume as NTFS and the other as EXFAT. So I tried to install exfat-utils.

I get "Could not resolve 'debian.map.fastlydns.net'????

I then tried apt update and nothing resolves... so I am stuck. So on with the fault finding...

- nslookup works fine
- dig works fine
- ping only works with ip address, not with domains
- wget and curl also fail to resolve

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 192.168.26.10
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

The local IP is my local PiHole, which I mainly use as a local DNS Server. All my other devices have the DNS Settings given by the main router via DHCP. Even this laptop I am typing this on, and everything resolves just fine.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found it...

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
hosts:    files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

Compared it with the copy on my local machine... so I duplicated the line, commented one out, and removed "resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]" from the other one.

Now it works